# Any work around for "Not a single group function" in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
ID |  UserID |  Time   |
3     9200    10/12/2016
2     9200    11/12/2016
1     9200    13/12/2016
4     1000    01/10/2017
5     1000    03/10/2017
```

Now I want to select the minimum date for a user id
i.e.,

```
userID      Time
9200        10/12/2016
1000        01/10/2017
```

i am using this but it throws an "Not a group by expression " or "Not a single group expression"

```
 select user_id, min(time) as earliest_date 
 from table
 where doc_id in (select doc_id from docs where description='some doc')
```

Any work around?
other than select where rownum=1

Comment: You need to do `GROUP BY UserID`.

Comment: Try by adding group by user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `group by`:

```
select user_id, min(time) as earliest_date 
from table
group by user_id;
```

If you want the entire rows with the minimum time, use an analytic function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,  min(time) over (partition by user_id) as mintime from t) t
where time = mintime;
```

If you want the `min()` on each row:

```
select t.*, min(time) over (partition by user_id)
from t;
```

Comment: That's incredible and really helps.Thanks for taking your time out to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select user_id, min(time) as earliest_date 
 from table
 where doc_id in (select doc_id from docs where description='some doc')
group by user_id
```

you have to use all the columns mentioned in SELECT statement in a group by except aggregated columns.